# Calculate field using a field from another feature class

Tags: arcpy

I have two feature classes, both of them are line features. I'm trying to the traffic count field (AADT) in the Road FC into the Bridges FC based on the distance between the two FCs, this distance being 15m. The other condition in assigning the AADT field to the Bridges FC is that road with the largest AADT field that is within the 15m threshold is chosen. I've already came up with code that assigns a score to each feature in the Bridges FC based on these AADT values (while still following the conditions I mentioned) below:

```
#Tuples that are used to calculate the score based on AADT, a and b are AADT ranges, c is
the score that gets assigned to the bridge
AADT_Tuple = [(0, 3999, 1),
            (4000, 7999, 2),
            (8000, 13999, 3),
            (14000, 19999, 4),
            (20000, 10000000, 5)]

##Tuple Calculation which does the same thing as the tuple above but for AADT counts
for aadts in AADT_Tuple:
    (minaadt, maxaadt, score) = aadts
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(roads, "justselected", "\"RM_AADT\" >="+str(minaadt)+ " AND \"RM_AADT\" <="+str(maxaadt))
    ##AADT = long("RM_AADT")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(bridges,"WITHIN_A_DISTANCE","justselected",15,"NEW_SELECTION")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(bridges, 'Soc_Traffic_Criteria', score)
    ##arcpy.CalculateField_management(bridges, 'Soc_Traffic_Criteria', AADT)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(bridges, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
    arcpy.Delete_management("justselected")
```

The two commented out lines in the for loop (the AADT variable and the 2nd calculate field) were my attempts to do what I'm trying to do but it didn't work. I was thinking of using either Update/Search cursors but I'm not sure how to implement it while still keeping the above code's functionality.

Comment: Have you tried using [cursors](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm)? They're much more versatile and easier than CalculateField.

Comment: @Tom I've tried using them yes it's just that I couldn't figure out how to keep the functionality that the tuple method I have provides.